# vizualize categorical and numerical values on the same plot

Tags: python, plot, dataframe, axis-labels, categorical-data

I have the dataframe, the story behind it: score of group student for every month, and the student that contributed the most in the recieving of such a score. What I would like is to plot the score as curve (or bar) and also to visualize the names o(probably as dot for line plot, or just name for every bar)

```
  Month     Score                _Max
     1         6                 Mike         
     2         5                 Alice
     3         9                 Eleonora
     4         11                 Helen
```

I'm using this method, which is messy, I know, and gives not readable x-ticks labels but I have no other idea how to deal with both categorical and numerical values in time series on the same plot

```
    df['index_col'] = df.index
    ax=df.plot(kind='bar', color=['red','blue'], figsize=(30,10))
    ax.set_xlabel("Month", fontsize=21)
    ax.set_ylabel("Score", fontsize=21) 
    labels = df._Max[:]
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation =90)
```

Comment: So you want a bar plot with people names on x-label, right?

Comment: I want a bar plot with months on x-axis, but, given the value for ```Max``` too (on x-labels ot just on the top of every bar stick)

Comment: How many rows does your data frame have?

Comment: more than 100 rows @gabra

Comment: This seems to be a visualization problem. Could the data be shown in more than one plot?

Comment: yes, I think it could be a solution, if there is no other way to plot it just once!

Comment: And if instead putting the name on top, how about using a color code to identify the names?

Comment: @gabra it's a great idea! can you provide some example of it, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
plt.bar(df['Month'], df['Score'], align='center')

for i in df.index:
    plt.text(df.loc[i, 'Month'], 12, df.loc[i, '_Max'],
             horizontalalignment='center')


plt.xticks(df['Month'])
plt.xlabel('Month')

plt.ylim([0, 15])
plt.ylabel('Score')
```

[image]

**Update**

Since you got several rows, I suggested that you could use color to categorize the names. I only knwo how to do it with [Seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/index.html).

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot('Month', 'Score', '_Max', df)
```

[image]